# zone detect when all task completed

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use the zones in angular 2 to detect when a group of task completes. I have the following code using angular2.0.0 beta 14

```
var count = 0;
Zone.fork({
    '+beforeTask': () => { if (count === 0) console.log('before'); },
    '+afterTask': () => { if (--count === 0) console.log('after'); },
    '+onZoneCreated': () => { console.log(++count); }
}).run(() => {
    this.http.get('/index.html').subscribe(response => {
        console.log('allo');

        setTimeout(() => console.log(response.text()), 1000);
    });
});
```

From what I understand, each fork will trigger a before task, after task and zone created. With this code it will log the following:

```
before
1
2
allo
after
1
<html><body>Hello world</body></html>
after
```

For some reason, the zone for the setTimeout was created after the 'afterTask' of the englobing task was called. The last count was printed after the wait time of 1000 milliseconds.

How can I detect when everything is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setTimeout task is actually executing under the same zone and shares the same execution context as the initial fork. The reason the afterTask event hook for the initial fork fires before the task queued by setTimeout completes is due to the semantics of setTimeout. If you need some details on the async semantics of Javascript there's a good article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

For the zone, the only instance where execution can be delayed is through an async task and these can be watched using the `enqueueTask` and `dequeueTask` props. You can combine these hooks with a scheduled task counter to determine when all tasks in a zone have completed, provided there are no events. [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vS9r3pJyuX5VYLCkdiK7?p=preview)